# How to iterate through and copy double pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address

I've created a two dimensional integer array in C, initialised it with values, and then cast it to an `int**` (I have to do that because it's for homework).
I've managed to iterate through it and set all of the values to 0. However, when I iterate through it again and print the values it, the output is not *all* zeros.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS    3
#define COLS    2

int main(void)
{
    /* Create array and convert to double pointer */
    int c[ROWS][COLS] = {{1,2},{3,5},{8,13}};
    int **ptr = (int **)c;

    /* Loop through entire array and print then double each value. */
    int *temp[ROWS];
    for(int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++){
        temp[i] = (int*)(ptr+i);
        for(int j = 0; j<COLS; j++){
            printf("Before setting: %i\n", temp[i][j]);
            temp[i][j] = temp[i][j]*2;
        }
    }

    /* Copy temp back into ptr */
    memcpy(ptr, temp, sizeof(ptr));

    /* Loop through array and print values */
    int *temp2[ROWS];
    for(int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++){
        temp2[i] = (int*)(ptr+i);
        for(int j = 0; j<COLS; j++){
            printf("After setting: %i\n", temp2[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

The issue is that the results are not what I would expect. One time I ran it, this was the output:

> Before setting: 1
>   Before setting: 2
>   Before setting: 3
>   Before setting: 5
>   Before setting: 8
>   Before setting: 13
>   After setting: -1193330832
>   After setting: 32764
>   After setting: 6
>   After setting: 10
>   After setting: 16
>   After setting: 26

The value `32764` is the same every time the program is run, but the value `-1193330832` changes each time (I assume it is the memory address of the array).

The output I was expecting is:

> Before setting: 1
>   Before setting: 2
>   Before setting: 3
>   Before setting: 5
>   Before setting: 8
>   Before setting: 13
>   After setting: 1
>   After setting: 4
>   After setting: 6
>   After setting: 10
>   After setting: 16
>   After setting: 26
>   because the values in the first loop have been doubled.

What have I done wrong? Why are the values changing and how should I actually go about fixing this?

(P.S. the homework doesn't involve finding a way to iterate through the double pointer, but I need to be able to do it to complete the actual task)

Comment: Can you say more explicitly tell the result you are expecting?Are you expecting the same results in `Before sampling`?

Comment: The values were doubled inside the loop, so I would expect 2*before sampling. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

`int **ptr = (int **)c;` isn't a valid pointer conversion, since you cannot use a pointer-to-pointer to point at a 2D array. Because it has nothing to do with 2D arrays.

Instead you can use a pointer to a 2D array, `int (*)[ROWS][COLS];`. The most convenient is however to use a pointer to a 1D array and have it point at the first element of the 2D array:

```
int (*ptr)[COLS] = &c[0];

...

ptr[i][j] = ...;
```

Fixed example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS    3
#define COLS    2

int main(void)
{
    /* Create array and convert to double pointer */
    int c[ROWS][COLS] = {{1,2},{3,5},{8,13}};
    int (*ptr)[COLS] = &c[0];

    /* Loop through entire array and print then double each value. */
    for(int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<COLS; j++){
            printf("Before setting: %i\n", ptr[i][j]);
            ptr[i][j] = ptr[i][j]*2;
        }
    }

    /* Loop through array and print values */
    for(int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<COLS; j++){
            printf("After setting: %i\n", ptr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

(A matter of style, but your order of ROWS and COLS is a bit weird, it is more common to do `int[COLS][ROWS]` then `for(i=0; i<COLS; i++)`)

Comment: The issue is that we are required to use `int **ptr` for the homework (because we were given function headers that we can't modify, and even our notes say `char data[3][4];`  `showData((char **)data);` where the function header is `void showData(char **d)`). Unfortunately this means I don't have much say in how I approach it, and I *have* to use `int **ptr`.

Comment: @JolonB But you can't use `int**` to point at 2D arrays. Maybe your teacher is confusing it with how to allocate pointer-to-pointer look-up tables dynamically. Those aren't 2D arrays either. Your teacher does perhaps not know C very well...

Comment: @JolonB Simply put, try this: `int **ptr = c;`. The compiler says "I can't do that because it's not a valid pointer conversion". And then when you change it to `int **ptr = (int **)c;` you tell the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing". Except it isn't true in this case, because the pointed-at data is not a pointer, nor is it an array of pointers.

Comment: (Also I feel like ROW then COL is more intuitive. Say you have an array of chars, then you could have char c[row][col], which means c[0] will return a horizontal array (as in c[0][0] to c[0][COL]) which can be traversed from left to right just like how you would read a word. Iterating through the columns first would mean you access the first letter of a word, then the inner loop would move to the first letter of the next word (on the next row))

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/LVt0JEY.jpg) is a screenshot of the notes, maybe I didn't explain it very well. I would hope it is correct, because I am paying almost $1000 to get taught this one course.

Comment: @Lundin I am not his/her teacher but you should not judge people you don't even know. It might be that Jolon did not understand the homework. Or even if he did there is no point in your comment

Comment: @JolonB Yeah that's hogwash and your teacher is incompetent. The correct function should be `void show_array (int array[ROWS][COLS])
{
  for(int i = 0; i<ROWS; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<COLS; j++){
      printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}` No casts anywhere or you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I'm just judging the code posted. Which any professional C programmer will dismiss as nonsense and undefined behavior. I do get upset when incompetent quacks teach C programming though. Means that someone has to un-teach and re-teach the poor students that they scammed.

Comment: Hmmm. That's super frustrating because the part that involves the double pointer is worth 40% of the assignment. I think I'll just have to accept that the first two values will be wrong. Thanks anyway

Comment: I how to agree with @Lundin that teacher have no clue what he is talking about.. you would think a teacher of C would know these things..

Comment: @JolonB Well, what you can do is to experiment by changing the data type and size until you provoke a crash, then have the teacher explain why it is crashing. I am able to repetitively provoke a crash with the teacher's code fairly easy on an online compiler here: https://onlinegdb.com/r1WW5EMuV. Output: segmentation fault (core dumped) as expected.

Comment: "*screenshot of the notes*": strange. 1st an array is hammered into a `char**`  which then in turn is hammered to be a `char*`  ... I'd asked the teacher why this.